# Can't save my render as an image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I seem to be having issues when I try and save the output file as a .png, or .jpeg for that matter. I've set up my user preferences, File, Render Output to my desktop as well as render output in the editor window. What am I missing here? I'm obviously very new to this program and your help would be appreciated.
Thanks for your time

Comment: Please expand your question giving details on how you are trying to save the image. What are you clicking on that you would expect to save the render as an image?

Answer (score 1):

Push the render button (or F12), then F3 to save the image.

Comment: Or set the frame range to one image only and press the animation button (or Ctrl F12). The rendered frame will be saved that way automatically using the settings on the output section.